# Creating a Hive schema in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Syntax for creating a schema in PySpark.

```
data.csv
id,name
1,sam
2,smith
```

```
val schema = new StructType().add("id", IntType).add("name", StringType)
val ds = spark.read.schema(schema).option("header", "true").csv("data.csv")
ds.show
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define StructType with StructField(name, dataType, nullable=True)

from pyspark.sql.types you can import datatypes

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType,FloatType,BooleanType
schema = StructType([
    StructField("col_a", StringType(), True),
    StructField("col_b", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("col_c", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("col_d", BooleanType(), True)
])
```